# Inserir valor recebido em javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
  <p>Your browser fingerprint: <strong id="fp"></strong></p>
  <p>Time took to calculate the fingerprint: <var id="time"></var> ms</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
var hasConsole = typeof console !== "undefined"

    var fingerprintReport = function () {
      var d1 = new Date()
      Fingerprint2.get(function(components) {
        var murmur = Fingerprint2.x64hash128(components.map(function (pair) { return pair.value }).join(), 31)
        var d2 = new Date()
        var time = d2 - d1
        document.querySelector("#time").textContent = time
        document.querySelector("#fp").textContent = murmur
        var details = ""
        if(hasConsole) {
          console.log("time", time)
          console.log("fingerprint hash", murmur)
        }
        for (var index in components) {
          var obj = components[index]
          var line = obj.key + " = " + String(obj.value).substr(0, 100)
          if (hasConsole) {
            console.log(line)
          }
          details += line + "\n"
        }
        document.querySelector("#details").textContent = details
      })
    }

    var cancelId
    var cancelFunction

    // see usage note in the README
    if (window.requestIdleCallback) {
      cancelId = requestIdleCallback(fingerprintReport)
      cancelFunction = cancelIdleCallback
    } else {
      cancelId = setTimeout(fingerprintReport, 500)
      cancelFunction = clearTimeout
    }
</script>
```

No form recebo este valores:

> Your browser fingerprint: e18982228d92dbaaf8d72492f16a059c
>
> Time took to calculate the fingerprint: 142 ms

Agora pretendo pegar nestes valores e inserir em mysql automáticamente ao iniciar sessão.

Estou a tentar desta forma, mas não está a inserir:

```
$teste1 = $_SESSION['usuarioId'];
 $teste4 = $_POST["fp"];
 var_dump($teste4);

if($teste4 != ''){
$query1 = 'UPDATE raddb.sessoes SET hostname= ? WHERE id = ? ';
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare( $query1 );
$stmt1->bind_param("ss", $teste4, $teste1); 
$stmt1->execute();
}
```

O problema é que quando faço `var_dump($teste4);` retorna como `NULL`. Não está a receber o valor da variável `fp` dentro do `javascript`

Answer (score 0):

Muda aqui:

```js
 $teste4 = $_POST["fp"];
```

Para

```js
 $teste4 = $_POST["murmur"];
```

Comment: mesmo alterando a variável teste4 fica NULL

Comment: A chamada para a função de POST no seu codigo tem que estar junto de ```Fingerprint2.get(function(components) { })```, por exemplo: ```Fingerprint2.get(function(components) { ... postFingerprint(murmur); })```

Comment: pode atualizar a resposta de como colocar essa parte do código dentro do javascript?

Comment: Posta seu código todo pra eu analisar direito como vai ficar

Comment: o código que tenho é esse, e funciona bem, retorna a identificação de cada dispositivo, o problema é só inserir este valor `e18982228d92dbaaf8d72492f16a059c`  na base de dados